# Alternative hudson user interface for job configuration

Tags: user-interface, hudson, jenkins

Is there any alternative user interface existing to Hudson apart from the one you can use in the web-browser. I guess it's possible to build one as Hudson exposes API for that, but was there ever built one?

I haven't found anything so far in Google. Does anyone of you know of something like that existing?

The reason I would like to have an alternative (most likely not web-based desktop client) is because I had to do a lot of configuration and I miss some advanced features (coping of steps, global search and replace, faster loading and caching of config) that might be available in alternative GUI.

I know that I can edit job configuration files by hand, but still it would be nice to do it in GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually copy the job and change what's needed, but if your jobs are largely similar then the Jenkins template plugin might be well-suited for your needs.

[Jenkins template project plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but plugin looks very limited:

Comment: * It may be using some plugins in ways that were not intended. Compatibility with all plugins is not guaranteed.
* It does not support project actions. That means that links that should be on the project page (e.g. 'latest test results') will not be there.
* It has had virtually no testing.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any plugins which offer an alternative view of the configuration page but there are a few for viewing other parts of the site in different ways:
http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View
http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hudson+Personal+View

If the issue is around creating new complex jobs you can do this by copying existing ones. Just use the 'Copy existing job' option when creating a new one.

Comment: And that's what I already do. I copy existing jobs and update configuration, but that's so much inconvenient and slow. Also I think it shouldn't really be a plugin, but a (desktop) client application for Hudson Job Configuration API.

Comment: @Andrey I suspect that your requirements are not those of a typical user. It's typical to spend much more time monitoring history than doing the initial configuration. You may have to create your own. Why would it need to be a desktop app?

Comment: It might also be a web-app as well. But doing a configuration of 50+ complex jobs is a bit painful in the existing hudson ui (slow loading, a lot of scrolling back and forth because of many different plugins installed, not possible to clone a step i.e. not the full job, but single step inside a job or copy single step between jobs = smth. like web clipbaord in gdocs). I know that I can achieve everything I need with existing UI and I know I can create new UI using briliant hudson API, but it was not part of the question :). I hoped that there is something more convient already existing.

Comment: Also, of course, at some point hudson setup will stabilze and we will only look at the history, but still now we are going through an active refactroing and testing phase of automated build/test/deployment (which I guess any project goes through) and it would of much help if configuration UI was more user-friendly than it is at the moment.